# What input parameters should I use in Keras Functional API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, functional-api

I am trying to write code for machine learning with Keras using Functional API. I am confused as to what input parameters to use.

```
# first input model
numbers_input = Input(shape=(,5,1))
conv11 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(visible1)
pool11 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv11)
conv12 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool11)
pool12 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv12)
flat1 = Flatten()(pool12)
# second input model
visible2 = Input(shape=(32,32,3))
conv21 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(visible2)
pool21 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv21)
conv22 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool21)
pool22 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv22)
flat2 = Flatten()(pool22)
```

It uses two types of inputs, Numerical and Boolean (1s and 0s). How can I use selected rows and columns in this code? The numerical inputs are from row 1 to row 44044 and columns 5 to 10. The boolean input ranges from rows 1 to row 44044 and column 1 to 4.

I tried to use the following syntax

```
# first input model
numbers_input = Input(shape=(1:44044,5:10,1))
conv11 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(visible1)
pool11 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv11)
conv12 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool11)
pool12 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv12)
flat1 = Flatten()(pool12)
# second input model
visible2 = Input(shape=(1:44044,1:4,3))
conv21 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(visible2)
pool21 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv21)
conv22 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool21)
pool22 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv22)
flat2 = Flatten()(pool22)
```

Comment: You need to preprocess your data to select the desired rows and columns before feeding it into your model.